# Compare two user defined curves and score their similarity

Tags: r, geometry, computational-geometry, curve

I have a set of 2 curves (each with a few hundreds to a couple thousands datapoints) that I want to compare and get some similarity "score". Actually, I have >100 of those sets to compare... I am familiar with R (or at least bioconductor) and would like to use it.

I tried the `ccf()` function but I'm not too happy about it.

For example, if I compare c1 to the following curves:

```
c1 <- c(0, 0.8, 0.9, 0.9, 0.5, 0.1, 0.5)

c1b <- c(0, 0.8, 0.9, 0.9, 0.5, 0.1, 0.5) # perfect match! ideally score of 1

c1c <- c(1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 0.9, 0.5) # total opposite, ideally score of -1? (what would 0 be though?)

c2 <- c(0, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0, 0.3, 0.3, 0.9) #pretty good, score of ???
```

Note that the vectors don't have the same size and it needs to be normalized, somehow... Any idea?
If you look at those 2 lines, they are fairly similar and I think that in a first step, measuring the area under the 2 curves and subtracting would do. I look at the post "Shaded area under 2 curves in R" but that is not quite what I need.

A second issue (optional) is that for lines that have the same profile but different amplitude, I would like to score those as very similar even though the area under them would be big:

```
c1 <- c(0, 0.8, 0.9, 0.9, 0.5, 0.1, 0.5)

c4 <- c(0, 0.6, 0.7, 0.7, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3) # very good, score of ??
```

I hope that a biologist pretending to formulate problem to programmer is OK...

I'd be happy to provide some real life examples if needed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We welcome biologist with an interest in quantifying uncertainty but I request that you drop your use of the term "curve" to describe uni-dimensional data. If these are always pair-able (1-1, 2-2 ...) meaning ordered and of equal lengths then a correlation coefficient, either Pearson or Spearman is where you should start.

Comment: Thanks for the support and helping describe properly the data. Yes they are ordered but almost never of the same exact length but roughly +/-10%...

Comment: This is the point where the statistical consultant asks for a bit of domain specific input. What are they, in reality? The next logical question is do they have any underlying scale, e.g. time, on which they can be honestly scaled or arranged.

Comment: DWin, each uni-dimensional vector represents the predicted folding state of a protein. Each data point is the folding score (between 0 = folded and 1=unfolded) of each amino acid. I want to compare those profiles for proteins that are orthologs (i.e. "the same") in two species (which is why I want to do pairwise comparison). For now, I focus on the one that are about the same length (i.e. size). This is a real big problem in the field, aka a full fledged formal solution will lead to publication in a peer reviewed comparative genomics journal (not there yet though ;)

Answer (score 2):

They don't form curves in the usual meaning of paired x.y values unless they are of equal length. The first three are of equal length and after packaging in a matrix the `rcorr` function in HMisc package returns:

```
> rcorr(as.matrix(dfrm))[[1]]
    c1 c1b c1c
c1   1   1  -1
c1b  1   1  -1
c1c -1  -1   1   # as desired if you scaled them to 0-1
```

The correlation of the c1 and c4 vectors:

```
> cor( c(0, 0.8, 0.9, 0.9, 0.5, 0.1, 0.5),
  c(0, 0.6, 0.7, 0.7, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3) )
[1] 0.9874975
```

Comment: That's really cool DWin!! Thanks!  During the eye balling phase, I was able to scale the uni-dimensional vectors in excel so they would be "stretched" to fit on the same x axis and be compared. Any idea on how I can scale each pair of uni-dimensional data so they are the same exact length and then use your proposed method?

Comment: I can think of at least one method and maybe two, but validity may depend on the granularity of the "observations", i.e. the degree to which one value is different from adjacent values compared to the overall range of values.

Comment: The granularity can be extreme, I have some real examples: ~ 300 data point per uni-dimensional vector. Can I upload a file with the data or send it to you directly?

Comment: I'd be willing to take a look. dwinsemius at comcast.net

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a very good answer, but I did face similar question in the past, probably on more than 1 occasion.  My approach is to answer to myself what makes my curves similar when I subjectively evaluate them (the scientific term here is "eye-balling" :).  Is it the area under the curve? Do I count linear translation, rotation, or scaling (zoom) of my curves as contributing to dissimilarity?  If not, I take out all the factors that I do not care about by selected normalization (e.g. scale the curves to cover the same ranges in x and y).

I am confident that there is a rigorous mathematical theory for this topic, I would search for the words "affinity" "affine".  That said, my primitive/naive methods usually sufficed for the work I was doing.

You may want to ask this question on some math forum.

Comment: Thank! Indeed I have been doing some "scientific eye balling" and see different patterns, as you mention (scaling, translation, duplication etc...). It would just be great to formalize that.  I had asked an engineer friend who had pointed me to signal processing algorithms: each line is a wave, like a sound, and what do you use to compare two waves (aka in voice processing algorithm). I thought it is an excellent suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If the proteins you compare are reasonably close orthologs, you should be able to obtain alignments for either each pair you want to score the similarity of, or a multiple alignment for the entire bunch. Depending on the application, I think the latter will be more rigorous. I would then extract the folding score of only those amino acids that are aligned so that all profiles have the same length, and calculate correlation measures or squared normalized dot-products of the profiles as a similarity measure. The squared normalized dot product or the spearman rank correlation will be less sensitive to amplitude differences, which you seem to want. That will make sure you are comparing elements which are reasonable paired (to the extent the alignment is reasonable), and will let you answer questions like: "Are corresponding residues in the compared proteins generally folded to a similar extent?".

Comment: Indeed Edvin, but there is more to the story. The folding prediction uncovered some treasures that were invisible to primary AA alignment: conserved folding in totally unrelated primary AA sequences, domains expansion etc..  Moreover, the predicted folding in the conserved region are virtually identical as the AA sequence is quasi-identical.

Comment: Very interesting. The manual pattern spotting makes sense then. If the interesting regions are not identifiable through either primary sequence alignment or structural alignment I think the best way of formalizing it is as an alignment algorithm. The Smith-Waterman algorithm can take almost any kind of scoring function, and with patient tweaking it might prove worthwhile. Good luck with that in any case.

Comment: Thanks Edvin! It is indeed very very interesting.